# How to add enum value in addScaler() method in Spring boot using postgresql?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums

I have an enum. But whenever I post it my data saved as number 0,1,2 in database. I don't know how this is happening. This is how I'm showing it to the front:

```
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;
import org.hibernate.type.EnumType;

        SQLQuery query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString());

        query.addScalar("id", IntegerType.INSTANCE);
        query.addScalar("school",EnumType ); // how to call enumtype here?
```

my post controller:

```
className.setSchool(SchoolType.FULL); //this is how i'm sending the school value
```

my enum:

```
public enum SchoolType {

    REGULAR("REGULAR"),
    FULL("FULL");

    private String label;

    SchoolType(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name();
    }

}
```

called it in my enity like this:

```
    @Column(name="school")
    private SchoolType school;
```

but the problem is isntead of going as reg or full , database is getting 0 or 1 value. How to resolve this? Instead of getting values , I'm getting enum key as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-enums) your should add the `@Enumerated` annotation:

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="school")
private SchoolType school;
```

if you want to store your enum's values as the enum value’s name, as indicated by `java.lang.Enum#name`

By default hibernate use `ORDINAL` mapping type for enum that is why your enum's values stored as ordinal numbers.

Comment: didn't work. If I give this then what should I send in addScaler("school", type).

Comment: i got error `expression expected` if i pass enum type like this in addScalar

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: hibernate veersion is 5.3.7.Final